# Using GridSearchCV to tune the parameters but there is an error when I tried to fit the datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is a tutorial that im doing for Scikitlearn machine learning. I was using 3 different classifiers in Scikitlearn which is decision tree, logistic regression and KNearestNeighbors. The individual classifiers worked fine and I combined them together into a ensemble learning algo using MajorityVoting which is represented as mv_clf in the codes.

These are the results of the classifiers

```
10-fold cross validation: 

ROC AUC: 0.92 (+/-  0.15) [Logistic Regression]
ROC AUC: 0.87 (+/-  0.18) [Decision tree]
ROC AUC: 0.85 (+/-  0.13) [KNN]
Accuracy: 0.92 (+/-  0.15) [Logistic Regression]
Accuracy: 0.87 (+/-  0.18) [Decision tree]
Accuracy: 0.85 (+/-  0.13) [KNN]
Accuracy: 0.98 (+/-  0.05) [Majority voting]
```

However, when I tried GridSearchCV to tune the parameters as a tutorial, there was an error in the grid.fit() function. I searched the documentation of GridSearchCV but i failed to understand why it fails to fit, because the output of the GridSeachCV seems fine.

```
params = {'pipeline-1__clf__C': [0.001, 0.1, 100.0], 'decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth': [
    1, 2], 'pipeline-2__n_neighbors': [1, 2]}
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=mv_clf, param_grid=params,
                    scoring='roc_auc', cv=10)
print(grid)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

print(grid) function output

```
GridSearchCV(cv=10,
             estimator=VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr',
                                                     Pipeline(steps=[['sc',
                                                                      StandardScaler()],
                                                                     ['clf',
                                                                      LogisticRegression(C=0.001,
                                                                                         random_state=1)]])),
                                                    ('dt',
                                                     DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',
                                                                            max_depth=1,
                                                                            random_state=0)),
                                                    ('KNN',
                                                     Pipeline(steps=[['sc',
                                                                      StandardScaler()],
                                                                     ['clf',
                                                                      KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)]]))],
                                        voting='soft'),
             param_grid={'decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth': [1, 2],
                         'pipeline-1__clf__C': [0.001, 0.1, 100.0],
                         'pipeline-2__n_neighbors': [1, 2]},
             scoring='roc_auc')
```

The print grid function has a normal output but when I tried to grid.fit(), there is an error and I am not sure why.

These are the errors that was shown after grid.fit() is called

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cheokjiaheng/Documents/Coding Projects/Tutorials/Python Machine Learning Book/Combining Diff Models/MajorityVoting.py", line 115, in <module>
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  File "/Users/cheokjiaheng/miniforge3/envs/tensorflowenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 230, in set_params
    raise ValueError('Invalid parameter %s for estimator %s. '
ValueError: Invalid parameter decisiontreeclassifier for estimator VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr',
                              Pipeline(steps=[['sc', StandardScaler()],
                                              ['clf',
                                               LogisticRegression(C=0.001,
                                                                  random_state=1)]])),
                             ('dt',
                              DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',
                                                     max_depth=1,
                                                     random_state=0)),
                             ('KNN',
                              Pipeline(steps=[['sc', StandardScaler()],
                                              ['clf',
                                               KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)]]))],
                 voting='soft'). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Comment: Why, while you are (correctly) using `clf` to refer to your `LogisticRegression`, you then decide that, instead of similarly using `dt` to refer to your `DecisionTreeClassifier`, you will use `decisiontreeclassifier`? Is `decisiontreeclassifier` (case sensitive) defined anywhere in your code? Similarly for your `KNN` further down...

Answer (score 0):

This question refers to some extent to the problem stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580199/hyperparameter-in-voting-classifier) and is due to the specification you make in the parameter grid. When tuning the hyperparameters for a `VotingClassifier`, you have to specify the key for the estimator in the `VotingClassfier` followed by `__` (two underscores) and then the attribute itself.

But, since two of your estimators are pipelines, you have to further specify the step, which is again separated by `__` (two underscores). This means your parameter grid should look like this:

```py
param_grid={
    'dt__max_depth': [1, 2],
    'lr__clf__C': [0.001, 0.1, 100.0],
    'KNN__clf__n_neighbors': [1, 2]
}
```

Again, for the `DecisionTreeClassifier`, you only specify its name that you chose when you instantiated the `VotingClassifier` object and the attribute name, and for the `Pipeline`, you need to specify its name, the step and then the attribute.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, please flag it as such instead of answering it.

Comment: @desertnaut the answer I linked to does not address how to handle the pipeline objects. This is why I think it's not really a "true" duplicate and it is worth leaving an answer that resolves the OP's question completely and not just partially. Otherwise, I would agree with you and just flag it instead of answering.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works now. Appreciate for the help and explanation.